# Accessing Azure tablestorage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am following this guide:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/

However, I'm running into problems at the step **How to: Create a table**.

First I have created storage called `tablestoragetest0`.

I am successfully getting a TableClient:

```
string ConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=tablestoragetest0;AccountKey=xxxxxxxx";
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConnectionString);
var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

But then when I try to create a table:

```
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("TestTable");
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

I get the following exception:

> The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'tablestoragetest0.table.core.windows.net'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your `ConnectionString`? Please replace account key text with something else when sharing.

Comment: Weird! I tried by creating a brand new storage account and the code above worked just fine. May I know in which data center have you created the storage account? Also, it could be related to some delay in DNS propagation so you may want to wait out a little bit.

Comment: I've put the account in West Europe. I created it before the weekend so DNS delay shouldn't be a problem. I have to note that when I look at the properties, I only see the URL for blob storage: http://tablestoragetest0.blob.core.windows.net/ but not for table storage.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce the error you're getting on a storage account I created in West Europe region. The error is coming for table service and not blob service. It seems something is going on at Azure level.

Comment: Thanks! I created a second account in North Europe and now it works. Can you post this solution as an answer so I can accept it, Gaurav?

Comment: Is your problem that Zone-Redundant Storage (ZRS) accounts DO NOT SUPPORT TABLES.

Comment: No, turns out something was going on with Azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce the error you're getting on a storage account I created in West Europe region. The error is coming for table service and not blob service. It seems something is going on at Azure level.